# What is the proper way to use time-series data for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, time-series, supervised-learning

I have a time-series dataset for a classification problem. The data contains brain signals collected via EEG eletrodes along 2 seconds in frequency (Hz). The classes are divided in different files (so each file contains only one class). This is a typical BCI (Brain-computer interface) classification problem, and as far as i know it is the usual way of separating classes for classification.

I want to know the proper way to prepare data for the classifier algorithms, since i have no X,Y values such as a common classification problem should have and the data is time-dependant. Any explanation/material is welcome.

I'm considering using `scikit-learn MLPClassifier` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community!

Well ... the answer needs a bit of explanation. It is not about MLPclassfier or another python function. It is about background in Signal Processing/Analysis specially for bio-signal.

For different bio-signals like EEG there has been feature extraction studies for long while. For example in your problem, BCI, you probably know [P300](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P300_(neuroscience)), etc which are common features (I am pretty outdated. You may have a look at recent review papers.). So usually you extract features from these signals and use them as the input of your classifier (those X, Y values that you mentioned). I explain a bit:

### In General

There are general feature extraction methods from signals. They either extracted from signal in [time-domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_quantification_analysis) or [frequency domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain) or [time-frequency domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%E2%80%93frequency_analysis).

Have a look at those links and get an overview.

### EEG

But for specific bio-signals you don't need to re-invent the wheel. There is a long history of methods for [EEg signal analysis](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7047620). For BCI in particular, there are again reviews to help you find good [feature extraction](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7079068) and [classification methods](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1741-2560/4/2/R01).

Finally my point is that, MLPclassifier is just a python function. According to my experience as a ML scientist coming originally from Biomedical Data Analysis, the question is more about "what to do?" before "how to do?". I hope it helped. If you had more questions please comment so I can update my answer.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your kind welcome and answer! In fact i already have an idea of "what to do" but since i've never worked with time-series data, i don't know how to present data to a classification algorithm. I know it is very common in BCI problems to use an entire file (records are separated by file, per user and per class) for a single class.